# How to format range of empty cells in xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, matplotlib, xlsxwriter

Is there any method to format range of empty cells in xlsxwriter.

e.g :

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Have you hag a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNq5I20xImU?

Answer (score 2):

I am aware of 2 ways, you can either use the worksheet.set_row method ( https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-row ), it is faster but it will expand the format until the end of the file, or you can specify the range using the write method:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cellFormat = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#8EA9DB', 'border': 1})

for column in range(3,12):
    worksheet.write(3, column, None, cellFormat)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]